# Changing variable in operator

Tags: calculus

I have an operator

$$\mathcal{L}_{\alpha} = \alpha^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \alpha^2}+\alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha},\quad \alpha = \cosh{\bigg(\frac{\theta(z)}{2}\bigg)}e^{i\phi(z)}.$$

I want to then write the operator in terms of $\phi$ and $\theta$ so
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha} = \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial\alpha}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}+\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial\alpha}\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}$$

but $\theta = 2\cosh^{-1}{(\alpha e^{-i\phi})}$ which doesn't help. Am I being really dumb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have$$\theta = 2\cosh^{-1}(\alpha e^{-i\phi})$$Then,$$\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial\alpha} = \frac{2e^{-i\phi}}{\sqrt{\alpha^2e^{-2i\phi}-1}}=\frac{2e^{-i\phi}}{\sqrt{\cosh^2(\theta/2) - 1}} = \frac{2e^{-i\phi}}{\sinh(\frac\theta2)}$$